# Scala, ZIO - convert Future into ZIO or ZIO into Future. Is it possible?

Tags: scala, future, scala-cats, zio

I created two versions of my service. First one uses `Futures`, other one uses `ZIO` as an effect.

I have a simple method which use `Future` as a result effect:

```
def get(id: String)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext): Future[Data]
```

I also has some other version which uses `ZIO[SomeEnv, SomeError, Data]`:

```
def get(id: String): ZIO[SomeEnv, SomeError, Data]
```

Now, I need to create some kind of adapter which will return data from one version or another one:

```
def returnDataFromServiceVersion(version: Int) : ??? = {
   if(version == 1) futureService.get(...)
   else zioService.get(...)
}
```

The problem here is with returned type. I do not know how to convert `ZIO` into future or `Future` into `ZIO` to have common return type. I tried use `ZIO.fromFuture{...}` or `toFuture()` but it did not help.
My question is - how to create this `returnDataFromServiceVersion` method to use it with both services? I need to have common return type here.

Or maybe there is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does the rest of your code use `ZIO` or `Future`? What errors did you receive trying to do `fromFuture`?

Comment: Rest are akka routes and I have only call this services to complete

Answer (score 6):

You have to decide whether your function returns `Future` or `ZIO` and this cannot depend on a runtime value like `version` in your snippet (unless of course you define the return type as `AnyRef` - not very useful).
If the rest of your program is based on `Future`s, but you would like to start introducing `ZIO` in some services, you can do that by executing your effects yourself using `runtime.unsafeRun(effect)`:

```scala
val runtime = Runtime.default

def returnDataFromServiceVersion(version: Int): Future[Data] = {
  runtime.unsafeRunToFuture(
    zioService.get(...)
  )
}
```

For more details refer to [Running Effects](https://zio.dev/docs/overview/overview_running_effects#default-runtime) in the official ZIO docs.

Comment: `runtime.unsafeRunToFuture` is what you are looking for I think. Currently this will cause this method to block the execution context.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @paulpdaniels! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what you want is common `ZIO` type which would look like this `ZIO[SomeEnv, SomeError, Data]`

That can be achieved using `ZIO.fromFuture` and mapping `Throwable` (which is `Future` failure type) to your `SomeError`:

```scala
  case class Data(data: String)
  case class SomeEnv(env: String)
  case class SomeError(err: String)

  object SomeError {
    def fromThrowable(throwable: Throwable) = SomeError(throwable.toString)
  }

  def getFuture(id: String)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext): Future[Data] = ???
  def getZIO(id: String): ZIO[SomeEnv, SomeError, Data] = ???

  def returnDataFromServiceVersion(version: Int): ZIO[SomeEnv, SomeError, Data] =
    if (version == 1)
      ZIO
        .fromFuture(executionContext => getFuture("id")(executionContext))
        .mapError(SomeError.fromThrowable)
    else
      getZIO("id")
```

Comment: `.mapError(SomeError.fromThrowable)` is it needed? I cannot use `fromThrowable` method here

Comment: Ah, my bad. It's custom method. I've added missing code to the original answer.